# Backport CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS to Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, csrf, csrf-protection, django-middleware

**The Problem:**

In Django 1.9, [`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins) was added to the available settings which allows to, for example, access the application from all the subdomains:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["*.example.com"]
```

Which is exactly what we need.

The problem is, we've got a legacy system with *Django 1.6* (don't ask, it is sad). Cannot upgrade.

And, in Django 1.6 the origin check is [built/hardcoded into the `csrf` middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.11/django/middleware/csrf.py#L156-L159).

---

**The Question:**
What is the best way to approach the problem? *Custom csrf middleware* instead of the built-in?

Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, basically, by *backporting* the [`csrf` middleware from Django 1.9](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py) manually to be compatible with Django 1.6. Not pretty, but works at the moment.